# How do i call stored procedure in php?

Tags: php, json, stored-procedures

I want to use stored procedure for insert statement in php.

I have created a sp and now i want to call the same in my php file.

**Below is my sp:**

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `radiolocous`.`insert_gmr`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `storedproc_test`.`insert_gmr`
(
IN version varchar(250),
IN visitorId VARCHAR(250),
IN dwellTime VARCHAR(250),
IN poiId VARCHAR(250),
IN srId VARCHAR(250),
IN zoneId VARCHAR(250),
IN poiProximityConfidence VARCHAR(250),
IN zoneProximityConfidence VARCHAR(250),
IN poiPresenceConfidence VARCHAR(250),
IN zonePresenceConfidence VARCHAR(250),
IN normalizedTime VARCHAR(250)
)
BEGIN


INSERT INTO gmr(version,visitorId,dwellTime,poiId,srId,zoneId,poiProximityConfidence,zoneProximityConfidence,poiPresenceConfidence,zonePresenceConfidence,normalizedTime)
values(version,visitorId,dwellTime,poiId,srId,zoneId,poiProximityConfidence,zoneProximityConfidence,poiPresenceConfidence,zonePresenceConfidence,normalizedTime);
END $$
DELIMITER;
```

My insert statement is something like:

```
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO gmr(version,visitorId,dwellTime,poiId,srId,zoneId,poiProximityConfidence,zoneProximityConfidence,poiPresenceConfidence,zonePresenceConfidence,normalizedTime)
                                VALUES ('" . implode("', '", $array) . "')")
                                or die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
```

How do i call the sp in my php, since i receive the values in a json, i not inserting it manually, but i have given sp parameter as **IN**

Is this correct?

I tried like:

```
$result = db_query("CALL insert_gmr('" . implode("', '", $array) . "')") or die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
```

I get Connect error without any description.

Is the problem in my sp or the way im calling in my php ?

Comment: _“I get undefined variable for $version,$visitorId, ...”_ – well do you have PHP variables by those names in the current scope? Do you even _mean_ those to be interpreted as PHP variables in that string? If not, go read the manual on the string type, and how variable parsing inside text literals happen.

Comment: That edit doesn’t make sense, it isn’t even valid PHP code.

Comment: I just updated a part of the statement where im calling the SP in php @CBroe, do u need the entire php code?

Comment: _“I get Connect error without any description”_ – well that’s likely because it is _not_ a connection error, but you only check for those. You are trying to perform a database query here - so you should use the correct function to ask the database if there were any problems with _that_.

Comment: Yes you are right, @CBroe, i had created sp in another DB and i had called it wrong, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your mistake is on the way you try to call your procedure.

In your case you should do something like that :

```
$result = db_query("CALL insert_gmr('".implode("', '", $array). "')"))
```

This way your call is correct as long as there are as many values in $array that there are parameters in your stored procedure

To know more about using stored procedure with PHP you can refer to the documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php

Comment: still i get connect error @EdgeSouls after updating as suggested

Comment: How do you connect to your database ? Do select or insert return the same error ? To be sure on how the CALL works in mysql you can try it in mysql command directly in your database. Also be sure that the implode return correctly the string with all the values, no char error like too much ',' or something ?

Comment: with my sql statement INSERT INTO gmr... values gets saved, but when i call with sp, i get connect error

Comment: Oh ok @EdgeSouls, got it, my database and stored proc was mismatch, thanks